# Mic Noise when i speak

Tags: sound

My sound card is "ALC888", when i use microphone on teamspeak 3, or Sound Recorder, anything, all i can hear and my friends, is noise, they don't hear my voice.
I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Anyone can help me?

Sorry, for bad english.

Answer (score 1):

The following instructions for installing the latest ALSA packages via the DKMS .deb installer worked for me on the Acer 5520.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS

Oneiric 11.10